# How do I apply a jquery Click event to dynamic list elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My current setup loads a dynamic list at which point I create a click event via jquery like so:

```
$('#listReports li').click(function () {
    var selected = $(this).text();
    alert("List Item: " + selected);
});
```

I have code that lets a user save a report which gets appended to the list.  The new item in the list doesn't trigger the click event until I call the function again.  The problem with this is for the older items the event is getting triggered twice.

Here is how I append my list items and call then function again:

```
            $("#save").click(function (e) {

                if ($("#reportParams li").size()> 0) {
                    var fileName = $('#reportFileName').val();

                    if (!fileName) {
                        alert("You must enter a file name!");
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#listReports').append('<li><a href="#">'+fileName+'</a></li>');

                        $('#listReports li').click(function () {
                            var selected = $(this).text();
                            alert("List Item: " + selected);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```

Is there a way to define the click event only once and have it effect new items appended to the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `.click()`, use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$('#listReports li').live('click', function ()
{
    var selected = $(this).text();
    alert("List Item: " + selected);
});
```

or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$('#listReports').delegate('li', 'click', function ()
{
    var selected = $(this).text();
    alert("List Item: " + selected);
});
```

Comment: that works great!  What is the difference between live and delegate?  Is one better then the other?

Comment: [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated in jQuery 1.7+. Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead